# Return type concrete type with unspecified generic

Tags: generics, rust, traits

In the below, the type returned by `make_nested()` is potentially very long so I would like to avoid needing to write out the entire type (first example). I would usually just return `impl MyTrait` in this situation (second example) but in this case I also want to enforce that the outer most type is `Foo`. So I would like to be able to return a `Foo<A>` from the `make_nested()` function where `A` is a not specified. The third example is my attempt at this but is not allowed. See comments in code for more info.

```rust
pub trait MyTrait {}
impl MyTrait for String {}
pub struct Foo<VT: MyTrait> {
    child: VT,
}
impl<VT: MyTrait> MyTrait for Foo<VT> {}

// Example 1: This is allowed but is too verbose
fn make_nested() -> Foo<Foo<Foo<String>>> {
    Foo {
        child: Foo {
            child: Foo {
                child: "hello".to_string(),
            },
        },
    }
}

// Example 2: This is allowed but doesn't enforce a Foo being returned
fn make_nested() -> impl MyTrait {
    Foo {
        child: Foo {
            child: Foo {
                child: "hello".to_string(),
            },
        },
    }
}

// Example 3: This isn't allowed
fn make_nested<A: MyTrait>() -> Foo<A> {
    Foo {
        child: Foo {
            child: Foo {
                child: "hello".to_string(),
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `impl Trait`, not a generic parameter. Just return `Foo<impl MyTrait>`:

```rust
fn make_nested() -> Foo<impl MyTrait> { ... }
```

Comment: Urgh I can't believe it was that easy haha, why didn't I try that! Thanks so much.